# Java JTable set AbstractTableModel in constructor after my code

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a class that extends `JTable`, and I want to set it's `AbstractTableModel`, but the only way I can see how that's possible is by calling the `JTable` constructor using `super`.

However, I need to initialize some variables (that hold the table data) *before* I call the constructor, which seems not to be possible ("call to super must be first statement in constructor"). How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the model after constructing the super class (i.e. `JTable`) by using the method [`setModel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel%28javax.swing.table.TableModel%29).

Comment: I had a suspicion there was a method like that, but for some reason I couldn't find it :) Thank you!